# read  XML String using C# 2.0

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML String, Using C# 2.0, I have to read that string and form a key value pair or separate lists. I have to use below XML for field mapping for Web Service.

below is my sample of my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Integration>
  <FiledMappings name ="Employee">
    <Field Name="EmployeeID">
      <DataSource>EmployeeNO</DataSource>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="Department">
      <DataSource>Department</DataSource>
    </Field>
    <Field Name="EmployeeName">
      <DataSource>Name</DataSource>
    </Field>
  </FiledMappings>
</Integration>
```

Comment: Should your o\p dictionary be something like this

`{
"EmployeeID":""EmployeeNO",
"Department":"Department",
.....
}` ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code; I used `Dictionary` and `XmlDocument`:

```
var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var document = new XmlDocument();
document.LoadXml(stringXml);
foreach (XmlNode node in document.SelectNodes(@"//Field"))
{
    keyValues.Add(node.Attributes["Name"].InnerText, 
                  node.InnerText);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works but in case if names changes in XML then it might not recognize the @//Field I posted my answer below which I have used XML Nodelist properties..

Comment: @msbyuva: my code just was a sample code. you must change it for your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code to get the required dictionary :

```
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
        s.AppendLine("<Integration>");
        s.AppendLine("<FiledMappings name =\"Employee\">");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"EmployeeID\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>EmployeeNO</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"Department\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>Department</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"EmployeeName\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>Name</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("</FiledMappings>");
        s.AppendLine("</Integration>");

        Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(s.ToString());

        XmlNode x = doc.ChildNodes[1].ChildNodes[0];
        foreach (XmlNode n in x.ChildNodes)
            d[n.Attributes[0].Value] = n.FirstChild.FirstChild.Value;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in d)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", p.Key, p.Value));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Or if it may appear to be possible to use .Net 3.5, you could utilize Linq to xml, please, see:

```
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.AppendLine("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");
        s.AppendLine("<Integration>");
        s.AppendLine("<FiledMappings name =\"Employee\">");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"EmployeeID\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>EmployeeNO</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"Department\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>Department</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("<Field Name=\"EmployeeName\">");
        s.AppendLine("<DataSource>Name</DataSource>");
        s.AppendLine("</Field>");
        s.AppendLine("</FiledMappings>");
        s.AppendLine("</Integration>");

        XElement x = XElement.Parse(s.ToString());

        Dictionary<string, string> d = x.Element("FiledMappings").Elements("Field").ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("Name").Value, e => e.Element("DataSource").Value);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> p in d)
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}:\t{1}", p.Key, p.Value));

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Obviously, my example has no validity checks and applies that the input xml string structure strictly follows the example given by msbyuva

Comment: FYI, if you're building up a string full of constants, just add (concatenate) them, it will be merged into a single string by the compiler. By throwing them in a string builder, you gain nothing and loose readability and some performance. Better yet, use a verbatim literal string if you want it to span multiple lines.

Comment: I am looking for something dyanamic.. as names may change in XML..  and I have to use .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0):

this is what I was able to do dynamically :

> ```
> private Dictionary<string, string> Load_XML_wsMapping(String _WSMapping)
>         {
>             // Web Service Mapping forms Key Value Pair
>             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(_WSMapping);
>             doc.LoadXml();
>             Dictionary<string, string> dictXMLMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>();
>
>             try
>             {
>                 XmlNodeList list = doc.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.ChildNodes;
>
>                 for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
>                 {
>                     XmlElement el = ((System.Xml.XmlElement)(list[i]));
>                     dictXMLMapping.Add(el.Attributes[0].Value, list[i].InnerText);
>
>                 }
>             }
>             catch (Exception err)
>             {
>
>                 throw new Exception("Error occurred while mapping Web Service -- Bad XML." + err.Message);
>             }
>             return dictXMLMapping ;
>         }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a disctionary for example below

```
 private static IDictionary<string, string> parseReplicateBlock(StreamReader reader)
```

Comment: What is `parseReplicateBlock`?